# What happens internally when you invoke a function in php

Tags: php, function, php-internals

A function defines the instructions which are to be taken when you invoke the function. That part is crystal clear to me. I also know that when functions are invoked that they are  placed on a callstack. But that's about it.

What happens internally when you invoke a function in php?

What should every (php) programmer know about callstacks? Any good resource available?

Comment: I doubt anyone really needs deeper knowledge about the internals of the php engine just to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Good strating point if you want to learn how internal `PHP` work :
[PHP7 virtual machine](http://nikic.github.io/2017/04/14/PHP-7-Virtual-machine.html)

Of course all article in `nikic` blog talks about how `PHP` works, I can recommend you also to read `jpauli` blog here [jpauli](http://jpauli.github.io/)